# Android SL4A (Python) Force Stop Packages fails.

Tags: python, android, task, kill, sl4a

I'm trying to terminate task using code like this:

```
import android

droid = android.Android()

running = droid.getRunningPackages()[1]

for task in running:
 if (task.find("skype") != -1)
  droid.forceStopPackages(task)
```

this works properly except killing call

```
`droid.forceStopPackages(task)` # When we get here, variable `task` contains "com.skype.raider" string
```

nothing happens after that. I expected that running skype application will be terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 2.2 (Froyo) killing apps is not really reliable. Play around with a task killer to see what I mean.